# Firebase facebook and google login error in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Here is my error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJhCM.png)Hello I am trying to login with Google and Facebook but it gives error.
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console. How to solve this error? Do I have also enable the services on firebase how to solve this problem?
here is my code

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btn_sign_up_login, btn_login, btn_gmail_login, btn_facebook_login;
    private ProgressBar pb_sign_up_login, pb_login;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuththenticatelistner;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleapiclient;
    public static final int RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN = 1;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btn_sign_up_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up_login);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_gmail_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gmail_login);
        btn_facebook_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
        pb_login = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_login);

        ///////////////////////////code for facebook login
        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                handleFacebookAccessTokens(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        });
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.web_api_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleapiclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btn_sign_up_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });
        btn_gmail_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
        btn_facebook_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleapiclient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DrawerActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {

        if (user != null) {
            String mailid = (getString(R.string.google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
            String idfor = (getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

        } else {
        }
    }


    // [START auth_with_facebook]
    private void handleFacebookAccessTokens(AccessToken token) {

        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END auth_with_facebook]
}
```

Comment: On which line you are getting this exception. Post your error screenshot.

Comment: i have added please check

Comment: And which dependencies are you using ?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

Comment: So you are setting all dependencies perfectly. First thing in your code Firebase is not initialized, try it. Because if we dont initialize firebase how the code determine from which firebase account this login function is connected.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to enable the authentication methods in the Firebase console. Navigate to Authentication>Sign-In Method and enable the required methods.

[image: Console]